# IChange Application Displayname's Font in IPhone

Tags: iphone

If i give iPhone application name maximum 12 characters then all characters will be displayed. But if I give more than 12 characters, then my application name display with (....). as below.

[image]

I want to need display fullname without showing (...). in my project. Or is there is any possible way to change application font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. You get what you get.

Comment: if i give 12 characters there is no problem. when i enter 13 characters then only displaying (...). If possibe There is Any way to change font size?